# Changing variable into string

Tags: ruby, string, variables

Please see the following code (taken from Learning Ruby book):

```
def timer(start)
  puts "Minutes: " + start.to_s
  start_time = Time.now
  puts start_time.strftime("Start time: %I:%M:%S: %p")
  start.downto(1) { |i| sleep 60 }
  end_time = Time.now
  print end_time.strftime("Elapsed time: %I:%M:%S: %p\n")
end

timer 10
```

Why would there be a need to change the `start` variable into a string on the puts line?  Couldn't I, for example, simply put in `puts "Minutes: #{start}"`?

Also, the `start.downto(1)` line: Is the block `{|i| sleep 60}` specifying how many seconds a minute should be?

Comment: It's only required if you want to see the time in a nice format with "Start time:..." etc in front of it, or if you want a specific date/time format.

Comment: I suspect you mean `def timer(start)`.  Reply not required, as I'll be deleting this comment.

Comment: Here is the documentation for [Kernel#sleep](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Kernel.html#method-i-sleep).  Note that `{ |i| sleep 60 }` can be written `{ sleep 60 }`, since the iterator variable `i` is not used.

Comment: I found that example on page 58 of the book you reference.  As I had suspected, `def timer` should be `def timer(start)`.  Please correct that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can also say:

```
puts "Mintues: #{start}"
```

It's one of many nice Ruby choices. :) In this case, it doesn't make much difference.

Regarding the loop:

```
start.downto(1) { |i| sleep 60 }
```

Yes, this is counting minutes down to `1` and each time is sleeping 60 seconds. So it will sleep for `start` minutes. If `start` isn't too large, you could just use `sleep 60*start`.